# APIM - response data masking

Tags: azure-api-management

we need to expose an internal API to vendor, however for development we need to mask the data the internal API replies, looking for a similar feature with apigee (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/security/data-masking), can this doable via APIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically, the Azure APIM allows flexibility on the handling of requests and responses, mainly with the concept of [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies). In short, these are operations that may be defined in the incoming, outgoing or during the execution of requests.

This allows the changing of the requests/responses (for example, adding or removing headers), which may be what you want. Some typical examples/snippets of policies are depicted [here in Azure's own GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets), as well as in APIM itself, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies).

These two walkthroughs may also be helpful: [Setting Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies) and [Transforming APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api).

Comment: not quite answer the question, any existing policies handles data masking, similar to apigee had? rather than individually interpret each backend api response via transformations manually

Comment: well, I don't know any equivalent to a "mask configuration"... You can set transformations such as [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies) or even [mocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#mock-response). The policies can also be set at different scopes, for example all the APIs, only one API or endpoint, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the header(s) you want to mask or remove, e.g. your subscription key, you can easily do it like this in the APIM policy:

```
<set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
```

Comment: I need to mask the content though

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the GitHub samples, I found this which appears to apply filtering to the response via the `<outbound>` policy

https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Filter%20response%20content%20based%20on%20product%20name.policy.xml

This was it at the time of writing:

```
<outbound>
  <base />
  <choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && context.Product.Name.Equals("Starter"))">
      <!-- NOTE that we are not using preserveContent=true when deserializing response body stream into a JSON object since we don't intend to access it again. See details on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody -->
      <set-body>
        @{
          var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
          foreach (var key in new [] {"current", "minutely", "hourly", "daily", "alerts"}) {
          response.Property (key).Remove ();
         }
        return response.ToString();
        }
    </set-body>
  </when>
</choose>
```